# trying to run this command to create a database with mysql but i get a "SQL Syntax error"

Tags: python, mysql

This is the error:
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database' at line 1`

Here is the code that I use to create the database:

```py
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd = "password12",
    )

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE database")

my_cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
for db in my_cursor:
    print(db)
```

I tried using a different name for the database, but I still got the same error.

Comment: I suggest you name your database something that is not a keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extraneous comma after your password parameter. Change your `mydb` connection string to the following:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = 'password12'
    )

my_cursor = mydb.cursor()

my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE database")

my_cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
for db in my_cursor:
    print(db)
```

You should use the word `password` over `passwd`. Even though they're synonymous, according to the MySQL documentation here: [Connector/Python Connection Arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html)

> An asterisk (*) following an argument indicates a synonymous argument
> name, available only for compatibility with other Python MySQL
> drivers. Oracle recommends not to use these alternative names.

| Argument Name | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user (username*) |  | The user name used to authenticate with the MySQL server. |
| **password** (**passwd***) |  | **The password to authenticate the user with the MySQL server.** |
| password1, password2, and password3 |  | For Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA); password1 is an alias for password. Added in 8.0.28. |
| database (db*) |  | The database name to use when connecting with the MySQL server. |
| host | 127.0.0.1 | The host name or IP address of the MySQL server. |

Also, *as mentioned in the comments above*, you should not use the word `database` as your actual database name. I understand you may be doing it as an example, but its worth noting that it is a [Reserved Keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#:%7E:text=DATA-,DATABASE,-(R)).

Comment: thank you and thanks for the advices, i actually just started learning flask and mysql etc yesterday so this is a big help :)